# Date range picker doesn't work on simple web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I try to add a date range picker like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jz4tpbrh/) on a simple web application.
I just have a html file, a css file and a javascript file.

So, in my files, I have the same things like in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jz4tpbrh/) and I have the same dependances but in my application, this doesn't work.

In my html file, I have :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 demo">
    <h4>Your Date Range Picker</h4>
    <input type="text" id="config-demo" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

And in the javascript file, I have :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
  var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
  var options={
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    container: container,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
  };
  date_input.datepicker(options);
})

$('#config-demo').daterangepicker({
"locale": {
    "format": "MM/DD/YYYY",
    "separator": " - ",
    "applyLabel": "Apply",
    "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
    "fromLabel": "From",
    "toLabel": "To",
    "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
    "daysOfWeek": [
        "Su",
        "Mo",
        "Tu",
        "We",
        "Th",
        "Fr",
        "Sa"
    ],
    "monthNames": [
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December"
    ],
    "firstDay": 1
},
"linkedCalendars": false,
"startDate": "09/26/2015",
"endDate": "10/02/2015",
"opens": "center"
}, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("New date range selected: " + start.format('MM-DD-YYYY') + " to " + end.format('MM-DD-YYYY') + " (predefined range: " + label + ")");
});
```

Do you have an idea why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Unless you show your relevant Javascript code, we can't help you.

Comment: I added my javascript file !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `$('#config-demo').daterangepicker` outside of the `$(document).ready()` function, which probably means you're trying to select the div with id "config-demo" before it exists in the DOM.

Move your `$('#config-demo').daterangepicker` call so that it's inside the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: Thanks ! It was that !